# How to manage login for Team Foundation Server, if we dont want to provide password of server to clients?

Tags: tfs

I would try my best to explain.
I have configured team foundation server on my server machine, and on client i can check in my projects on server and on other clients i can get final version. It is working correctly.
Now i have two questions. 
**1-** From client pc, when  i connect to team foundation, it asks for username and password, and on team foundation server the password configured there is the same password of server  windows admin credentials. I try to create any other user on it but i think so i must have to create a server admin account for this. But i dont wana give my server credentials to clients. It seems to me quite dangerous. See the image.
[image]

**2-** If i do some changes and i do check in, it works good. And changes are loaded there. On other client, if i do check out, it did not get the latest different changes, it does nothing. But when i do get latest version then it works fine but bring all latest changes and merge. Why check out does not get only "different" statement changes among them?

I am newbie TFS, so kindly forgive me if i am asking something fool.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to resolve this.
Just create a new account on your active directory.
And use it for login. Provide that account here
[image]

Now i can provide this username and password which i created as a user account on active directory.